# Is restarting redmine server necessary after configuration change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, mediatemple

I have a Redmine site installed in Mediatemple DV. I am currently having some problems in email configuration. I've changed the configuration like this:

```
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
production:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
address: "myOutgoingMailServer"
port: 25
authentication: :plain
domain: 'mySiteDomain'
user_name: 'emailAddressInsideSingleQuote'
password: 'passwordInsideSingleQuote'
```

Do I need to restart the server to make sure that the changes in the configuration work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's important.

After modifying the configuration.yml in Redmine,

Restart the server to get that effect.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to restart the Apache web server service which hosts Redmine.